# 'dist' directory is not generated even if after running 'nuxt build' in Travis CI

Tags: firebase, travis-ci, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting

The Travis CI console tells that 'dist' direvtory does not exist.
Although after running "nuxt build".

I'm trying to deploy Nuxt project (SPA mode) to Firebase with Travis CI.
With following code and console message, Can you think of anything that might have caused it?

.travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 10.16.0
dist: trusty
sudo: false
branches:
  only:
  - master
  - develop
install:
  - yarn global add firebase-tools nuxt
  - yarn install
  - nvm install 11.11.0
script:
  - nvm use 11.11.0
  - yarn build
deploy:
  provider: firebase
  skip_cleanup: true
  token:
    secure: $FIREBASE_TOKEN
  project: $FIREBASE_PROJECT
  on:
    branche: develop
```

Travis CI Job log

```
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.3.2
(node:5376) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
$ nuxt build
Done in 43.26s.
The command "yarn build" exited with 0.
$ rvm $(travis_internal_ruby) --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl

Installing deploy dependencies
Preparing deploy
Deploying application

=== Deploying to '[FIREBASE_PROJECT]'...

i  deploying storage, firestore, hosting
i  storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
✔  storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
i  firestore: reading indexes from firestore.indexes.json...
✔  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully

Error: Specified public directory 'dist' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site [FIREBASE_PROJECT]
Firebase deployment failed

failed to deploy
```

Comment: Can you try adding `ls -al` right after calling `nuxt build` in your .travis.yml file to see if the directory really exists?

Comment: I tried to add `ls -al` then directory `dist` does not exist.